# VS11 Black Background when printing

Tags: printing, visual-studio

When I try to print my Sourcecode from Visual Studio 11 RC, the Code gets printed as white on black, not the other way around.
I tried searching for it in Enviroment- Colors- Printer, but I don't see anything wrong there.

The header of the pages is fine, just the code is wrong.

I use a dark skin, but that shouldn't make a difference for the printing?
I also tried "Use Defaults" in the color settings for Printer and Text-Editor.

EDIT: It seems to work now if I choose the light skin and restart VS. If I switch back to the dark skin, it again doesn't work.

Comment: Does it happen to all file types (*.cpp, *.h, *.cs, *.pas, *.txt...)? Did you try to print to pdf, for example to PDFCreator? Did you reset settings (tools > import/export settings > reset)?

Comment: See my edit. I tried resetting the settings, no luck. Yes, I tried printing to pdf.

Comment: Nice to know you found a way to print, although you could not do it on dark skin...

Comment: No, I use the windows standard skin. Notepad printing works fine, no wrong colors there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if you are still interested in finding an answer to this, but it looks like in Visual Studio 2008 at least you can set the printing format separate from the text editor format by going into the settings.

go to this link [How to: Print Code in the Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zh337ws%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) under the section labeled color printing it points you to another link [Fonts and Colors, Environment, Options Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw7t0545(v=vs.90).aspx)  where it tells you how to set the printed output format separately from the Text Editor code.

I am unsure about the version that you are using, if these same options are available or not in the toolbar menus.

---

in Visual Studio 2010

- Tools
- Options
- Environment
- Fonts and Colors

then it will look like this.

[image: Options Dialog]

and you can choose the print option and set everything to the normal Visual Studio "Light" theme